# Implementing a package returns: Module util does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement this package into my project https://www.npmjs.com/package/feedparser I have literally copy-pasted the example code. 
The only thing I changed is

> import FeedParser  from 'feedparser';

As a result, I get an error in my metro builder:

> Unable to resolve module util
>   from/Volumes/DEV-DRIVE/jaco/test/NieuwsApp/node_modules/feedparser/lib/feedparser/index.js:
>   Module util does not exist in the Haste module map.

Any Ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`util` is part of the node.js api. feedparser is designed to run in node.js not react native. You may be able to make it work regardless by installing the `util` package from npm.

```
npm i --save-dev util
```